# How to manage 2 canvas in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

i am using `fabric.js`, now the problem is that i want 2 canvas to draw object its a t-shirt designer and i want to design front and back both side. now i want that if any person click flip it changes the canvas and show the other canvas and draw all on that and on again flip its comes to the previous one.

here is the [link](http://jamie.ideaservers.net/web/gotogear/designer.php) i am working with.

i want to print other side of this shirt

Comment: even after the edit i can't understand what is your question. Be more specific with what are you asking, do you have problems implementing the flip functionality or you're asking for an advice of how to implement it right ?

Comment: Arty thank sor your reply let me clear i am using a jquery tool for canvas drawing name fabric.js. what i as having issue was about using multiple canvases. i am success in that now the problem is that when i switch to other canvas by show hide the properties. selection doesn't work

Comment: did you try to call canvas.calcOffset().renderAll() on your active canvas (after the swap) ?

Comment: yes have tried but still not working

Comment: ok, so i don't know how to help you. sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give auto generated id for each of the canvas,
E.g for front it would be

```
<div class="front-canvas">
<canvas id="1_workarea1"></canvas>
<canvas class="upper-canvas" width="200" height="350"></canvas>
</div>
```

And for Back it would be

```
<div class="back-canvas">
<canvas id="2_workarea2"></canvas>
<canvas class="upper-canvas" width="200" height="350"></canvas>
</div>
```